# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" in python

Tags: python

```
def get_hidden_card(credit_number, star_count=4):
    short_credit_number = str(credit_number[12:16])
    return str('*' * star_count + short_credit_number)


print(get_hidden_card(2034399002125581))
```

As i understand python don't wanna work because he think that str(credit_number[12:16]) is int type, how can i fix it?

The error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(get_hidden_card(2034399002125581))
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 4, in get_hidden_card
    short_credit_number = str(credit_number[12:16])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You're looking for `str(credit_number)[12:16]`. I.e. *first* turn the `int` into a `str` and then get the slice. You cannot get a slice from an `int`.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit and the code simple you 're doing `2034399002125581[12:16]` you can't, you need a sting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is must solve your issue

```
def get_hidden_card(credit_number, star_count=4):
        short_credit_number = str(credit_number)[12:16]
        return str('*' * star_count + short_credit_number)
    
    
    print(get_hidden_card(2034399002125581))
```